# Complexity of ZF precoding at the transmitter

Tags: signal-analysis, optimization, mimo

If we have a modulated signal $s$ and ($m\times n$) MIMO channel $H$ where $m$ and $n$ are number of receive and transmit antenna, respectively. The ZF pre-coded signal is
\begin{equation}
x=Fs
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
F=H^H(HH^H)^{-1}
\end{equation}

How do I calculate computational complexity of ZF precoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: you will be disappointed, this doesn't give you a number, but it tells you what to research to figure this out, as this quickly becomes very complicated and specific to your actual channel. If you think this was covered in class, forward this text to your professor and ask her or him to clarify.**

The precoder $Fs$ is just a matrix multiplication. So, the complexity in terms of multiplications is identical to the number of elements in $F$. **Or so it seems,** in a naive implementation. So, if you're trying to analyze how complex such a system would be, the answer

> Well, it's the number of elements in $F$, as the lecture slides say I need to calculate the product $Fs$

is wrong.

You give a formula, $x=Fs=H^H(HH^H)^{-1}s$, but that involves an inverse of a hermitian matrix.

We [**do not** actually compute the matrix inverse](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/12/09/matrix-inversion/) to then multiply it with a vector¹.

There's optimized algorithms for solving the matrix-vector product (instead of inverting the matrix) if the matrix is hermitian, which $HH^H$ is; sadly, that's numerical math in its optimized form, and which I'm not familiar enough with.

Together with the fact that in systems where you'd want to do the ZF, you often couldn't reuse the same $F$ very often, as your estimate of the channel either gets better over time as you can average out noise, or your channel changes too fast for much reuse, this means your question is really one for the numerical math experts, and I doubt there's a general answer – in the end, actual dimensions and condition of $HH^H$ do matter. **Especially** if attenuation/lack of good channel estimation means that $HH^H$ is not well-conditioned, computing the inverse to do ZF is unnecessarily damaging to the quality of the precoding.

Anyways, overall the complexity would be:

1. Solving $Ab=s$ for $b$, as that's the same as $A^{-1}s$, but faster to compute than the inverse and the product
2. Computing the (smaller in its dimensions!) product $H^Hb$.

Note that both of these steps are *probably* not what makes your ZF precoder expensive – it's the estimation of $H$, but that's usually done at the other end and communicated back; but in compute-constrained scenarios, the transmitter might have to do the estimation of $H$ itself, based on a more or less unprocessed received signal observation sent back by the receiver, in which case it's a whole different game.

---

¹ in this case, you'd calculate $H^H\left(B^{-1}s\right)$, **not** $\left(H^HB^{-1}\right)s$, as that would already save some effort: Two matrix-vector products are cheaper than one matrix-matrix product plus a matrix-vector product.

Comment: This is with the assumption that the channel coherence time is long enough and the estimation is perfect to make it simple to analyze the ZP alone.  Thanks Marcus for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Riva11 That just means that you can reuse a single inverse often; that might or might not be sufficient to actually make that desirable, but as said, numerically, it's advantageous to just solve $Ab=s$ for $b$ instead of finding $A^{-1}$, and the points where it's advantageous are exactly the points of high noise amplification that people (rightfully) warn you about as being the downside of ZF.